# WordPress menu to change page title

Tags: wp-admin

I am using `wp_list_pages`.  I am unable to change page title
For eg:- I made a page with name `lorem ipsum` and want to show in content area the same name i.e `lorem ipsum`.  But in menu, I want to show the name `lorem`. How to do this.

Comment: consider creating a custom menu with `wp_nav_menu()` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu which should allow what you want; http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen

Comment: Michael is right. You can then enter a "Navigation Label" to use just for the menu while the actual page title stays untouched.

Comment: Yes, you are rite, but i want 100 menu items. and due to my server problem, i am not able to show 100 menu items, it does not display above 65 items.

Answer (score 1):

@Michael is right using wp_nav_menu() is the easiest route to go for this. If your menu (with your server problems) is only allowing to show 100 items you could consider splitting it up in to two menus.

Using wp_nav_menu() is the easiest way to go and creating two menus using the label atribute is equally easy.

First you would register the menus. This code gets added in your theme's functions.php.

```
// This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in two locations.  
register_nav_menus( array(  
  'primary' => __( 'Primary Navigation', 'your_theme_name' ),  
  'secondary' => __('Secondary Navigation', 'your_theme_name')  
) );
```

This will register two menus. Then put this where your menu is to go in your theme:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'secondary' ) ); ?>
```

Then style it how you want so that they work seamlessly together.